# How to check windows process parameters

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm starting Tomcat server with start.sh script on Windows, there are some default parameters like "-Dcatalina.hom=xxx". After it's started, open "Task Manager", I can only see a process named "java" which is related to my Tomcat, however, I want to see its parameters **without any command**, I don't want to use command like ps, jinfo and so on, so does someone know is there a place i can find those tomcat process parameters?

Comment: Since the tools you listed give you the information you have asked for can you please explain why those tools are not sufficient in your case?

Comment: because running command has many restrictions, I'd like a reliable way such as registry, file or WMI to do that

Answer (score 2):

You can go to `View -> Select Columns...` on `Task Manager` and select `Command Line`

[image]

Now there could be several `java.exe` processes, if I am not wrong you should be able to identify Tomcat's by searching for string "tomcat" in one of the command strings.

An example `Command Line` for a `java.exe` is shown as below :

[image]

Comment: However, this can't meet my requirement, it just shows "java", not including other arguments or options

Comment: @sudo You should be able to see the `Command Line` in the columns as shown in the pic posted in my answer. For example in that pic, the arguments are : `-Xms128M` , `-Xmx256M` etc.